# Dataframe to sheet and save in xlsm in a specific sheet

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

I am trying to save data from a pandas dataframe and then to save it to xlsm file. However, I have a problem. I have found a method to get data to openpyxl, but how do I save it?

```
    from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
    import pandas as pd
    from openpyxl import load_workbook

    prices = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Fred', 'Jane', 'Alice', 'Margaret'], 
         'street': ['Baker Street', 'Downing Street', 'Baker Street', 
         'Castle Street'],
         'stamp': ['', 'T03', '', ''],
         'city': ['', 'London', '', ''],
         'other irrelevant columns for this task' : [1, 2, 3, 4]
          })
    book = load_workbook('test.xlsm', keep_vba=True)
    ws = book.active
    rows = dataframe_to_rows(prices, index=False)
    for r_index, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
        for c_index, value in enumerate(row, 1):
            ws.cell(row=r_index, column=c_index, value=value)
    book.save('test.xlsm')

This is the error I am getting: KeyError: "There is no item named '[Content_Types].xml' in the archive"
```

Full traceback of the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PATH\scripts\prices.py", line 57, in <module>
    book = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsm')
  File "PATHPython39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 317, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "PATHPython39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 276, in read
    self.read_manifest()
  File "PATHPython39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 134, in read_manifest
    src = self.archive.read(ARC_CONTENT_TYPES)
  File "PATHPython39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1463, in read
    with self.open(name, "r", pwd) as fp:
  File "PATHPython39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1502, in open
    zinfo = self.getinfo(name)
  File "PATHPython39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1429, in getinfo
    raise KeyError(
KeyError: "There is no item named '[Content_Types].xml' in the archive"
```

Comment: Your example uses both `book` and `wb` for workbook. `prices` is also not provided. Using random data for `rows` I am unable to reproduce the error. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Ok, I have corrected the code. Prices is the dataframe. I want to replace whatever was in the xlsm with the new dataframe.

Comment: I suspect the file is defctive. Please provide the complete traceback of the error.

Comment: No problem, I have added the full traceback. The file seems ok to me, I can open it in excel, there is no error when I open it in excel

Comment: Again, running your code as provided above does not reproduce the error. Does running this code exactly produce the error as shown in your traceback?

Answer (score -1):

My mistake was that I was saving `dataframe.to_excel` before I was writing it to the XLSM file. When I commented out `prices.to_excel('test.xlsx')` The code worked.

so what I discovered I cannot have is:

```
prices.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

When I commented it out it worked.

```
#prices.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

Comment: Hello, Congratulations on you first answer.
To make it easier for people, try to be concise in your answer on how to resolve the problem.
This will allow people to spot the fix directly

Comment: @Aylinn how is this an answer to your question? There was no line `prices.to_excel('text.xlsx')` in your question

Comment: I wanted to make it simpler so as not to write the whole code and it didn't cross my mind when I asked that it can matter.